# Problem with Kotlin reordering LinkedHashMap keys

Tags: java, kotlin, treemap, linkedhashmap

My goal is to get keys from a `LinkedHashMap` in the order that they are stored in the Map in `Kotlin`. I have this working in `Java`, but `Kotlin` is doing it differently.

I have a base class with 2 subclasses. One subclass sets the map to `LinkedHashMap` and the other to `TreeMap`. Both the ordered and unordered subclasses have all their functionality in the superclass. The base class uses a `Map` in Java, a MutableMap in `Kotlin` because I need to mutate the map frequently. How do I get the keys from a `MutableMap` in order in `Kotlin` if I am using a `LinkedHashMap` as the base? I can see they are in order when using the debugger.

I am using a sealed base class with 2 subclasses, and whether or not the elements are sorted by order is the difference between the subclasses.

Here is the working Java code:

```
protected Map<T, Double> map; 

if (comparable) {
    this.map = new TreeMap<>();
} else {
    this.map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}

public List<T> getKeys() {
    return new ArrayList<>(this.map.keySet());
}
```

and the broken Kotlin code:

```
protected var map: MutableMap<T, Double>

map = if (comparable) TreeMap() else LinkedHashMap()

val getKeys = ArrayList(map.keys)
```

I tried using an iterator, but the iterator does not reset!
NoSuchElement when there should be?

```
        var keys = map.iterator
        assert(keys.next().key == 0)
        assert(keys.next().key == 1)
        assert(keys.next().key == 2)
        pf.swapPositions(2, 1)
        keys = map.iterator
        assert(keys.next().key == 0)
        assert(keys.next().key == 2)
        assert(keys.next().key == 1)
```

```
val iterator = map.iterator()
```

Comment: What is `pf`?  And where/how does the test code fail with the Kotlin implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference I can see is that `val getKeys` is not at all equivalent to Java's `public List<T> getKeys()`; that would be

```
fun getKeys() = ArrayList(map.keys)
```

or

```
val keys get() = ArrayList(map.keys)
```

The code you wrote evaluates `ArrayList(map.keys)` only once, during construction, when the map is likely empty.

This may not be the *only* problem; if it still doesn't work after you fix it, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Sidenote: in Kotlin, it's more idiomatic to write `map.keys.toList` or `map.keys.toMutableList` instead of directly using the `ArrayList` constructor unless you really need an `ArrayList` in particular.